# Fetch multiarray JSON object from python script over the AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem fetching JSON string object from python script. 
When I click submit button, I can see in console that the request respond with code 200 and I see the JSON object too, but no changes on the index.php...

Thank you for any help you can provide in this situation.

*Python script returns JSON like this:*

```
    {
        "test": {
            "t1": {
                "alias": "PT-LAUSANNE101",
                "in": 135853.51,
                "out": 111948.23
            },
            "t2": {
                "alias": "PT-LAUSANNE102",
                "in": 2597.35,
                "out": 1815.86
            },
            "t3": {
                "alias": "1ABET",
                "in": 3469.19,
                "out": 562.29
            },...
        }
    }
```

*Here is AJAX call from JS:*

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#get_b" ).click(function () {
        $( "#get_b_wrapper tbody" ).html('');
        var from =$( "#from_date" ).val();
        var to = $( "#to_date" ).val();
        var dataString = 'data={"from":"' + from + '","to":"' + to + '","summary":true}';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/srv/v2/bal",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json', 
                success: function( result ) {
                    var t = $( "#get_b_wrapper tbody" );
                    $.each( result, function( i, row ){
                            t.append( '' + row.alias + '' + row.in + '' + row.out + '' );
                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                    console.log( 'DONE' );
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

*Here is index.php file:*

```
    <label>From:</label>
    <input type="text" id="from_date" class="date_picker form-control" value="" />
    <label>To:</label>
    <input type="text" id="to_date" class="date_picker form-control" value="" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="get_b">Submit</button>
    <table id="get_b_wrapper">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th>Deposits<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                <th>Payouts<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(`result.test`):

```
 success: function( result ) {
                var t = $( "#get_b_wrapper tbody" );
                $.each( result.test, function( i, row ){
                    t.append( '' + row.alias + '' + row.in + '' + row.out + '' );
                });
```

Instead of this:

```
 success: function( result ) {
                var t = $( "#get_b_wrapper tbody" );
                $.each( result, function( i, row ){
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/e5yCp/